# How and where does Chrome fetch the history when it’s in incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome, security, privacy, private-browsing

I often visit/browse websites in incognito mode of Chrome. Chrome doesn’t save the history, cookies while in Incognito mode. But recently I noticed I can view the full website address while I type first letter of the website.

Have a look at this screenshot to see what I mean:

[image]

If the Chrome doesnt save cookies where does this suggestion come from? It doesn’t seem to be fetching the results from Google since I checked this setting at offline too and saw the same behavior. Where does Chrome load this information from?

Comment: Afaik incognito mode in chrome does save information but deletes it once *all the windows have been closed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome deletes Incognito history only after *all of your incognito windows have been closed*. This allows the user to login to a website while in Incognito mode. Otherwise, you would login to a website, and it would immediately delete the cookie with your login data, logging you out again.